# Converting with imagemagick in php to webp returns empty string

Tags: php, imagemagick, webp

I installed imagemagick with webp support on my ubuntu system and when i run

```
convert pic.jpg pic.webp
```

on console everything works fine. But when i try to do the same in php/hhvm i get only a empty string (no error); just string(0) ""

```
$image = new Imagick('pic.jpg');
$image->setImageFormat("webp");
var_dump($image->getImageBlob());
```

When i replace webp by png or gif i get the expected result. 
Result of $image->queryFormats() shows also webp support

Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9 libwebp-dev 0.4.4 HipHopVM 3.11.1

anyone an idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev` maybe?

Comment: already done..otherwise convert to webp on console wouldn't run neither .. but i tested it now with "normal" php and it works, so seems to be a hhvm problem:(